# Finding whole number solutions to nonlinear equations?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Is there a general way of finding whole number solutions to nonlinear equations like the following?

Given $a,b$ and $c$: $ay^2+bx^2= c $

Given $a$ : $y = \sqrt{ a + x^2 }$

Given $a,b$ and $c$: $y = \sqrt{ax}+bx^2+c$

I have found nothing in my math classes so far about this.
Regards!

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1048219